# Openlayers 4 map in white

Tags: openlayers

I have a OpenLayers 4 map with a vector layer. Sometimes it turns into white while still having the zoom in and zoom out buttons. What could be the reason?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! AS a new user, please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to get accustomed i.a. with the expectations of a *good* question; as it stands, it´s hard to tell what you are looking at and what the reason could possibly be among millions. When does that exactly happen? What exactly happens? Where do you get the vector data from and what service are you using?

Comment: please add your code